# 2006 Subaru outback won't accelerate

Tags: fuel-system

My 2006 Subaru outback has now three times stops accelerating completely but engine runs normal. The check engine light comes on also. A friend thought it had water in fuel line put in dry heet and hours later it runs again and engine light goes off. First time it went a couple of months before it happened again but recently it was only 4 days before it happened again...any ideas at what is happening?

Comment: Welcome to the site! What engine is in your Outback?

Comment: automatic or manual transmission?